# How to fix the following error: Trying to get property of non-object?

Tags: codeigniter

How to handle this error?

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: views/email_templates.php

Line Number: 57

Backtrace:

File: C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\EcommerceGiondaCI\application\views\email_templates.php
Line: 57
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\EcommerceGiondaCI\application\controllers\Cpages.php
Line: 596
Function: view

File: C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\EcommerceGiondaCI\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

views/email_templates.php

```
<?php foreach ($email as $email_item): ?>

                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $email_item->email_title; ?>account_invitation</td>
                            <td>preview</td>
                            <td><button type="button" class="edit" onclick="location.href = '<?php echo site_url('cpages/editemailtemplate/'.$email_item->email_id); ?>';">EDIT</button></td>
                            <td><button type="button" class="delete" href="adminform.php">DELETE</button></td>  
                        </tr>
```

models/pages_model.php

```
public function call_email()
    {

            $query = $this->db->get('email');
            return $query->result_array();                  

    }
```

views/email_templates.php
Line Number: 57

```
Line 57:  <td><?php echo $email_item->email_title; ?>account_invitation</td>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php) (Specifically, this section: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26572398/1427878)

Comment: @David try below answer.

Answer (score 1):

Depending of what you want to fix (either the result to the call to your model, or the empty result it might give), I would test the array for existence before trying to use it:

```
if (isset($email)) {
    if (is_array($email)) {
        //your code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Model.Try like this..

public function call_email()
    {

```
        $query = $this->db->get('email');
        return $query->result();                  

}
```

`result_array()` gets row in array format.But for you get result in object format using `result()` because in view you accessing elements using arrow operator.For more see  https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html

Hope it will work perfectly.